# How can I draw multiple lines of text with drawAtPoint?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, quartz-graphics

I am custom drawing some text:

```
point = CGPointMake(77, 5);
    [[message valueForKey:@"user_login"] drawAtPoint:point forWidth:200 
                                            withFont:mainFont 
                                         minFontSize:MIN_MAIN_FONT_SIZE 
                                      actualFontSize:NULL 
                                       lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation 
                                  baselineAdjustment:UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines];
```

How can I make it draw 5 lines? Equivalent to:

```
rect = CGRectMake(77, 25, 238, 68);
bodyLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
bodyLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12];
bodyLabel.numberOfLines = 5;
bodyLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    bodyLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.contentView addSubview: bodyLabel];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation for `-drawAtPoint:withFont:...` says "This method does not perform any line wrapping during drawing." If you use `-drawInRect:withFont:` instead of `-drawAtPoint:withFont:...`, then it will draw multiple lines. You can also use `-sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:` to figure out what the size will be.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deprecated `drawInRect:withFont:...` in iOS7+ you should use `drawWithRect:options:attributes:context:`

```
[string drawWithRect:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)
             options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine
          attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:<font>, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:<color>
             context:nil];
```